# Is there any way to read the contents of svg file placed under asset folder in angular other than Http/fetch?

Tags: angular, svg

I am trying to fetch the contents of .svg file placed under ***/assets/image*** in angular cli project.

Ex:

```
 /assets/image/1.svg
 /assets/image/2.svg
```

I am not able to use '**fs**' module as browser will not support node native fs module. Using http we can achieve this but it will be very costly operation as there are 1000s of icons.

I am searching for an efficient way to import contents of .svg into angular component.

Angular version: 9

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around except using HttpClient. If you have many svg files you can merge them into a single svg asset and download this one only using HttpClient. It will be more efficient.

Here you can find a good Angular component how to merge SVG files into a single spritesheet and use it in your application - https://github.com/jannicz/ng-svg-icon-sprite